# AngularJS - After Filtering The Model Isn't Updated

Tags: angularjs

I just wanted to see if anyone has had experience with the issue I having. I am currently populating a select element from a restful web service using the ng-options feature and assigning it to my model with ng-model. I have also applied a filter to this select that changes the list based on the value from another select element. Everything works as intended from the display side. If I change the master select element and it filters the second select to not include the currently selected item, the display shows correctly and displays 'please select'. So this looks great and works as I intended but when this scenario happens the underlying model isn't updated and still has the invalid option stored in it. If I pass the model back to the server for further processing, I am getting values that might not be valid.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to have selected that filter one another also update the underlying model ?

I appreciate any ideas.﻿

Comment: please show your code. Also creating a simple demo in  plunker or jsfiddle.net helps

Comment: Hard to help you if you don't show your code. I'm gonna take a wild guess and say it's because you're using primitives instead of objects.

Comment: I would think you need to put a $watch on the ng-options array length, if it changes, see if the current ng-model value is still in the array, if it's not, set the value to null or something.

Comment: I was able to get it working by using a $watch. Thank you for your suggestions.